# How to add scraped items into a set and execute when condition is met?

Tags: python, scrapy

This piece of code is expected to add extracted reviewId into a **set**( in order to omit duplicates. Then there is a check, when set lenth is 100 - callback is executed and long url string with all ids is passed to main extract function.

How do i do this(*Save all ids, extracted from different callbacks into same Set and use it further*) either with built in tools or with the code i have? the problem now is that lenth check loop is never enetered. 
UPdate. I believe there are two options - pass Set as meta to each callback and somehow use Item for this one. But donno how.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response



class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tripad"
    list= set()

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60763-d122005-Reviews-or{}-The_New_Yorker_A_Wyndham_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html#REVIEWS"

        for i in range(0,500,5):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url.format(i), callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        for result in response.xpath('//div[contains(@id,"review_")]/@id').extract():
            if "review" in result[:8]:
                QuotesSpider.list.add(result[7:] +"%2C")
            if len(QuotesSpider.list) == 100:
                url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/OverlayWidgetAjax?Mode=EXPANDED_HOTEL_REVIEWS&metaReferer=Hotel_Review&reviews="

                for i in QuotesSpider.list:
                    url+=i
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_page)
```

Comment: You can use simpler xpath expression `//div[@class="reviewSelector"]/@id` instead of  `//div[contains(@id,"review_")]/@id`. It return only `id` value: `review_somenumbers`

Comment: thank you. I will.  but that is not the question here) Sorry if it was not clear. Have edited it abit.

Comment: is there a reason why you want to yield the urls only when the list is 100 long? Also you should never store any sort of state in class or instance parameters when using scrapy, since the whole system is concurrent, you will run into a lot of problems because the parameter is being modified at multiple places at the same time.

Comment: In your use case I'd advise you to split spider into two spiders. One crawls review ids (then you can put it in a file) and the second one opens up this file and crawls reviews themselves. There's another a bit more advance solution and I can write up an answer for it but I'd recommend going with the splitting.

Comment: @Granitosaurus the reason was limitation of tripadvicer. url could return 100 or 150 reviews in one page but not more. Though now it is not important as it appears some reviews fail to load completely. Its a shame, as in my understanding the less requests i made the ess pages i load the faster it works.

Comment: Basically, for now i will generate urls on the fly. so the only question here is how to avoid saving duplicate reviews.

Comment: What are you trying to acquire? Why not just send a request for each review ID?

Comment: @Casper  Efficiency. I can load 150 reviews with single request. On the contrary, i will have to send 150 requests to get each single review.

Comment: @Granitosaurus  How do i automate passing ids from one scraper to another? or doing so with file.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this, however I'd advise splitting your spider into two parts:

Spider that collects review ids

```
class CollectorSpider(Spider): 
    name='collect_reviews'
    def parse(self, response):
        review_ids = ...
        for review_id in review_ids:
            yield {'review_id': review_id}
```

Spider that uses collected review ids to collect review content

```
class ConsumerSpider(Spider):
    name='consume_reviews'
    def start_requests(self):
        with open(self.file, 'r') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
        last = 0
        for i in range(0, len(data), 100):
            ids = data[last:i]
            ids = [i['review_id'] for i in ids]
            # make url from ids
            url = ''
            yield Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        # crawl 100 reviews here
```

Comment: thanks you. i see the logic. But the process needs to be automated. How will second spider know when to open the file(like when the collector is done)? I read something about pipelines, where you can do some stuf like chcking on size of items or start and run spdiers. But not ready to implment this thing yet.

Comment: it won't know. However you can put both spiders in a script and since 1 crawl of the spider will be blocking the other spider won't start untill it's finished. See [How to run scrapy from a script](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)